# jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find() not working in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below JSP code in which tr has ID and last child td has ID. I want to have style updated for the last child td. How could i do this:

```
<tr class="${rowClass}" id="${loopStatus.index}" >
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>    
    <td id="uploadedDiv" >
                    <div id="success" style="display:none">
                    <div class="floatLeft selectWidth15">
                        <div class="available"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="floatLeft selectWidth85 greenText"><fmt:message key="opusmx.upload.uploaded" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="failure" style="display:none">
                    <div class="floatLeft selectWidth15">
                    <div class="notAvailable"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="floatLeft selectWidth85 redText"><fmt:message key="opusmx.upload.captureFailed" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

The below function works only on web browsers but not as an app in iPad. Can someone help me on this:

```
function showStatus(elementID,thisObj,status){
                if (status == 'success') {
                    jQuery(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find('#uploadedDiv').find('#success').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    jQuery(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find('#uploadedDiv').find('#failure').css('display', 'block');
                }
        }
```

Comment: Whenever you're doing `.parent().parent().parent()`, you're doing something wrong. The element has a ***unique identifier*** (ID), all you need is `$('#success').show()`

Comment: -adeneo Its an iterator. If I just use $('#success').show(), It always gets displayed only for 1st row in jsp

Comment: Sounds like your rows are using the same ID for each last `<td>`, which would explain why the first row gets shown.

Comment: Cory - tr has an unique id for all rows.  Based on the row I am clicking, I have to display the message

Comment: There should only be ***one*** element with the ID `#success` in the entire document, hence why it's called a unique identifier, so targeting that single element would be done with `$('#success')`. If you have more than one element with that ID ***in the entire document***, jQuery will only find the first one, always.

Comment: adenoe-you are right. #success is an unique id but it is associated with all tr. I have to make the #success work for the corresponding tr

Comment: I don't get it, if you only have ***one single element*** with that ID, how does it correspond to a row? There's no reason to do `parent->parent->find->ID` when the ID ***must always be unique***, and can be easily looked up without climbing the DOM-tree. I'll try this again, there can ***only*** be one single element with a given ID, not one in each row with the same ID, but one in each entire document, or in other words the entire page your viewing.

Comment: Based on your code, #success is not associated with all `tr`s. In your code, #success is 1 div inside one row only.

Comment: you could try parents with some selector init

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using the id of tr tag. It found out the children and set the required style:

```
function showStatus(elementID,thisObj,status){
            if (status == 'success') {
                jQuery('#'+elementID).find('#uploadedDiv').find('#success').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                jQuery('#'+elementID).find('#uploadedDiv').find('#failure').css('display', 'block');
            }
    }
```